# Google Ads LoadArgs is undefined

Tags: adsense

Anyone has encountered the problem with google ads? when I open firebug in firefox I found one error it is said "**window.google.ads.LoadArgs is undefined**". A problem occurs when I use **Google Custom Search**. Please give me a solution if you guys know about it. Thanks